# Can I apply for work visa for Ireland and Netherlands at same time?

Tags: netherlands, ireland

I have got a job opportunity in Ireland, but I might get a better opportunity in the Netherlands in the next 2-3 weeks.

Can I apply for a Netherlands ex-pat visa while Ireland CSP is still in progress? Can I decide at a later point which opportunity to take? And inform the other one to cancel the work permit.

Comment: Why wouldn't you be able to?

Comment: Thanks, Phoog .Since both of the countries are part of EEA. Shouldn't it cause any trouble?

Comment: I think it unlikely.  I'll try to write a proper answer in a few hours or tomorrow.

Comment: Thanks, Phoog. Really appreciated! I'll be looking forward to it.

Answer (score 1):

I presume that "Ireland CSP" is actually CSEP.

Yes, you can apply for any other visa while CSEP is in process. But please keep in mind, that CSEP is a quite expensive thing, it costs 1000 euro and can be refunded only if not yet processed. Also it has some costs to prepare the docs. I think the sponsor may ask you to pay the prices in case of your cancellation.